# jQuery takes 1st value and shows the same on all

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to convert timestamp into time ago. It works perfectly but when my page has too many timestamps this code takes only fist timestamp and shows 1st time on all timestamps.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var time = $('.timestamp').attr('datetime');
    var time2 = format_date(time);
    $('.timestamp').html(time2);
}); 

<abbr class="timestamp" datetime="1370993104">0 seconds ago</abbr>

<abbr class="timestamp" datetime="1370854140">0 seconds ago</abbr>

<abbr class="timestamp" datetime="1370627340">0 seconds ago</abbr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it using the [.html( function(index, oldhtml) )](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function syntax.

```
 $('.timestamp').html(function(){
    return format_date($(this).attr('datetime'));
  });
```

Issue with your current code is that with your selector `$('.timestamp').html` you always set the same value for all of them and while getting `$('.timestamp').attr('datetime');` you only get the value of the first one.

One more thing is the attribute datetime is not valid, so consider using ``` data-*`` attributes, i.e ```data-datetime` and access the attribute value using [jquery data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) provided you are not planning to change the attribute value on the fly and retrieve using data.

```
<abbr class="timestamp" data-datetime="1370993104">0 seconds ago</abbr>
```

and you can change your code to

```
  $('.timestamp').html(function(){
      return format_date($(this).data('datetime'));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jQuery's getter methods (those methods, such as `attr()`, `html()`, `text()`, etc, without arguments) if called on a collection of elements returned by a selector, will return only the information from the *first* element of that set, not, as you seem to think, an array.

And, even if it *did* return an array, jQuery wouldn't automagically iterate over that array by guessing your intent. So, that said, you need to iterate over the elements returned by the selector, and update them individually, thankfully most methods natively provide for iteration using the anonymous function. So, that said, you need to use:

```
$('.timestamp').html(function(){
    return $(this).attr('datetime');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yFqCH/).

The above iterates over each of the elements, and sets the HTML (though really you should use `text()` since you're not needing to recreate the HTML content of the given element) to be equal to the `datetime` of the *current* element, rather than the variable you created earlier.

So, really, I'd suggest:

```
$('.timestamp').text(function(){
    return $(this).attr('datetime');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yFqCH/1/).

If you'd rather use an external variable, though, you could use the following approach (though I don't really see why you'd want to):

```
var times = $('.timestamp').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('datetime');
}).get();

$('.timestamp').text(function(i){
    return times[i];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yFqCH/2/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

`attr` delivers a single value. You need to loop over the elements if you need to do something with an attribute value of each one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timestamp').each(function (){
       var time = $(this).attr('datetime');
       var time2 = format_date(time);
       $(this).html(time2);
    });

});
```